# Find variable combinations that makes Primary Key in R

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

Here is my toy dataframe.

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~var1, ~var2, ~var3, ~var4, ~var5, ~var6, ~var7,
    "A",   "C",    1L,    5L,  "AA",  "AB",    1L,
    "A",   "C",    2L,    5L,  "BB",  "AC",    2L,
    "A",   "D",    1L,    7L,  "AA",  "BC",    2L,
    "A",   "D",    2L,    3L,  "BB",  "CC",    1L,
    "B",   "C",    1L,    8L,  "AA",  "AB",    1L,
    "B",   "C",    2L,    6L,  "BB",  "AC",    2L,
    "B",   "D",    1L,    9L,  "AA",  "BC",    2L,
    "B",   "D",    2L,    6L,  "BB",  "CC",    1L)
```

How can I get the combination of a minimum number of variables that uniquely identify the observations in the dataframe i.e which variables together can make the **primary key**?

The way I approached this problem is to find the combination of variables for which distinct values is equal to the number of observations of the data frame. So, those variable combinations that will give me 8 observation, in this case. I randomly tried that and found few:

```
df %>% distinct(var1, var2, var3)

df %>% distinct(var1, var2, var5)

df %>% distinct(var1, var3, var7)
```

So vars123, vars125, vars137 deserves to the Primary Key here. How can I find these variable combinations programmatically using R. Also, more preference should be given to character, factor, date, and (maybe) integer variables, if possible, as doubles should not make the Primary Key.

The output could be list or dataframe stating combinations "var1, var2, var3", "var1, var2, var5", "var1, var3, var7".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit of a variation on the other answers, but here's the requested tabular output:

```
nms <- unlist(lapply(seq_len(length(df)), combn, x=names(df), simplify=FALSE), rec=FALSE)
out <- data.frame(
  vars = vapply(nms, paste, collapse=",", FUN.VALUE=character(1)),
  counts = vapply(nms, function(x) nrow(unique(df[x])), FUN.VALUE=numeric(1))
)
```

Then take the least number of variables required to be a primary key:

```
out[match(nrow(df), out$counts),]
#        vars counts
#12 var1,var6      8
```

Comment: That's a very elegant solution!

Comment: Filtering count by number of rows in main dataframe and then by minimum number of variables used should fetch one of the better candidates for the Primary key. So...suggesting a small edit.

Comment: Let's keep var4,var6 and var4,var6 as well in the output as both provide  least number of variables required to be a primary key.

Answer (score 3):

There may be a better way, but here's a brute-force method

```
combs <- lapply(seq(ncol(df)), function(x) combn(names(df), x, simplify = F))

keys <- list()
for(i in seq_along(combs)){
  keys[[i]] <- combs[[i]][sapply(combs[[i]], function(x) nrow(distinct(df[x])) == nrow(df))]
  if(length(keys[[i]])) stop(paste('Found key of', i, 'columns, stopping'))
}


keys

# [[1]]
# list()
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1] "var1" "var6"
# 
# [[2]][[2]]
# [1] "var4" "var6"
# 
# [[2]][[3]]
# [1] "var4" "var7"
```

Comment: Thank you! Can we try use purrr, feed all name combinations into select() %>% n_distinct() and have the output in the dataframe so that one column contains all the possible combinations of variable names and the other column contains the n_distinct values. We may need the help of rlang, here.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a brute force method enumerating all possible combination of variables. It seems like there are 80 possible combinations that meets your criteria.

```
>df
  var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7
1    A    C    1    5   AA   AB    1
2    A    C    2    5   BB   AC    2
3    A    D    1    7   AA   BC    2
4    A    D    2    3   BB   CC    1
5    B    C    1    8   AA   AB    1
6    B    C    2    6   BB   AC    2
7    B    D    1    9   AA   BC    2
8    B    D    2    6   BB   CC    1

>n<-ncol(df)
>combinations<-unlist(lapply(1:n, function(x) unlist(apply(combn(n,x),2,list), recursive=F) ), recursive=F)
>length(combinations)
[1] 127
>count_distinct<-sapply(combinations, function(x){ nrow(unique(df[,x,drop=F])) } )
>length(which(count_distinct==8))
[1] 80
>combinations[which(count_distinct==8)]
[[1]]
[1] 1 6

[[2]]
[1] 4 6

[[3]]
[1] 4 7

[[4]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[5]]
[1] 1 2 5

[[6]]
[1] 1 2 6

[[7]]
[1] 1 2 7

[[8]]
[1] 1 3 6

[[9]]
[1] 1 3 7

...
```

Comment: Can we have the variable names instead of their numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Possible approach:

```
library(dplyr)

lst <- c()

for (i in 2:ncol(df)) {

  lst_combinations <- combn(names(df), i ,simplify=FALSE)

  lst <- c(lst, lst_combinations)

}

lst_results <- c()

for (i in 1:length(lst)) {

  nms <- lst[i][[1]]

  lgth_df <- df %>% .[, colnames(.) %in% nms] %>% distinct() %>% count()

  if (lgth_df$n == nrow(df)) {

    nms <- paste(nms, collapse = ", ")

    lst_results <- c(lst_results, nms)

  }

}
```

First few combinations (found 80 in total for your example):

```
[1] "var1, var6"                              
 [2] "var4, var6"                              
 [3] "var4, var7"                              
 [4] "var1, var2, var3"                        
 [5] "var1, var2, var5"                        
 [6] "var1, var2, var6"                        
 [7] "var1, var2, var7"                        
 [8] "var1, var3, var6"                        
 [9] "var1, var3, var7"                        
[10] "var1, var4, var6"
```

Comment: Thank you! Can we try use purrr, feed all name combinations into select() %>% n_distinct() and have the output in the dataframe so that one column contains all the possible combinations of variable names and the other column contains the n_distinct values. We may need the help of rlang, here.

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing completely from thelatemail's answer and converting that to purrr:

```
library(tidyverse)

m_in_comb <- seq_len(length(df))

var_combs_listoflist <- map(m_in_comb, ~combn(x=names(df), m = .x, simplify=F)) %>% 
  unlist(recursive = F)

var_combs_listofchr  <-  map_chr(var_combs_listoflist, ~paste(.x, collapse = ","))

distinct_obs_per_var_comb = map_int(var_combs_listoflist, ~(select(df, .x) %>% n_distinct()))

keys <- tibble(var_combs = var_combs_listofchr, distinct_count = distinct_obs_per_var_comb)

primarykeys <- keys %>% 
   filter(distinct_count==nrow(df)) %>% 
   mutate(n_vars = str_count(var_combs, ",")+1) %>% 
   filter(n_vars==min(n_vars))
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this help? [https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dm/vignettes/howto-dm-theory.html#:~:text=3.-,Primary%20Keys,is%20called%20a%20compound%20key](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dm/vignettes/howto-dm-theory.html#:%7E:text=3.-,Primary%20Keys,is%20called%20a%20compound%20key).

"Primary Keys In a relational data model, each table should have one or several columns that uniquely identify a row. These columns define the primary key (abbreviated with “pk”). If the key consists of a single column, it is called a simple key. A key consisting of more than one column is called a compound key.

Example: In the airlines table of nycflights13 the column carrier is the primary key, a simple key. The weather table has the combination of origin and time_hour as primary key, a compound key.

You can get all primary keys in a dm by calling dm_get_all_pks():

```
dm %>%
dm_get_all_pks()
dm_enum_pk_candidates() #checks suitability of each column to serve as a simple
```

#primary key:
dm %>%
dm_enum_pk_candidates(airports)

Further Reading: The {dm} package offers several functions for dealing with primary keys."

Comment: Why did I not know about this earlier!! Is this a new package? It has everything I was looking for. Thanks for sharing!